# What kind of indexing are used in MyISAM and InnobDB engines?

Tags: mysql

I read that `InnobDB` uses `B+ Tree` and `Clustered` indexing on Primary Key and `Hash(H) Tree` and `Non Clustered` indexing on multiple keys (unique key).

But I did not get any explanation for `MyISAM`..

And what I read for `InnobDB` is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct regarding the InnoDB. For MyISAM see below

```
B-tree indexes  Yes T-tree indexes  No  Hash indexes    No
```

Read Here [more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)